# Why do i got an error 91 with checkbox on word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a document on Word with some content control.

I found this code on internet to hide the content control who are empty (some of them are optional)

When the macro reach a checkbox, i got an

> error 91

How can i fix that ?

```
Sub
    Dim controle As ContentControl
    Dim cont_texte

    For Each controle In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    cont_texte = controle.Range
        If cont_texte = controle.placeHolderText Then
            controle.Range.Font.Hidden = True
        Else: controle.Range.Font.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No one memorizes the error numbers - what's the error TEXT?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try using set, like this:

`set cont_texte = controle.Range`